# React Native: Can't style the Button

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am quite new to React Native. I am familiar with React and use it for my work. React Native seems different in terms of applying styles to the components.

I am having issue applying styles to the button.

Here is my current code:

```html
<Button
  title="LET'S GET STARTED"

  onPress={() => {
    console.log('You tapped the Decrypt button!');
  }}
  buttonStyle={{
    backgroundColor: "#0A6ABB",
    width: 300,
    height: 45,
    borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 5
  }}
  containerStyle={{ marginTop: 50 }}
/>
```

I tried multiple ways, but the styles are not being applied the button that I have created.

Here is the screenshot of how it looks like:
[image]

"Let's get started" is the button and no matter what it just has the default blue text. 
How can I fix this?
Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Which framework are you using or is that a vanilla react native element?

Answer (score 1):

Is your `Button` component imported from `react-native`? If yes then you can't style it because as stated on their [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html), below are the supported props, `buttonStyle` is not supported prop. Alternatively, maybe you can try other packages like Button from [react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.0/button.html) or [NativeBase](http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#button-def-headref)

- onPress
- title
- accessibilityLabel
- color
- disabled
- testID
- hasTVPreferredFocus

Answer (score 0):

`Button` is very limited in react native. You can use `TouchableOpacity` instead to give you more flexibility See [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html) here.

`TouchableOpacity` example:

```
render () {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.button}
      onPress={this.onPress} >
      <Text> LETS GET STARTED </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    padding: 10
  },
});
```

There are also different kinds of "buttons" depending on what you need like `TouchableHighlight`, `TouchableWithoutFeedback`

Answer (score 0):

Use  `TouchableOpacity`

```
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text }
render() {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => { console.log('You tapped the Decrypt button!'); }}
        >
          <Text> LET'S GET STARTED </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      button: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: "#0A6ABB",
        width: 300,
        height: 45,
        borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginTop: 50
      },
    });
```